# How to make an If function in excel that evaluates if there is text or not in one column, and then outputs "n" (text) or "y" (no text)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If word in column A, then output "n" in column B. If no word in column A, then output "y" in column B. How to create this function in excel?
I want it to look like this: (but not do it manually)
[image]

Comment: `=IF(B1="","y","n")`.

Comment: Couldn't find a better duplicate link but the principle is the same: test if the cell `=""`.